# Recurrence Relation / Difference Equation Problem

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the following recurrence relation, but I am doing something wrong all the time when trying to find the particular solution, and I cannot figure out what.

$y_k+4y_{k-1}+4y_{k-2}=(-2)^k$

To try to find the particular solution, $y_k^p$, I do the following:

$y_k^p=Bk^2(-2)^k$, and I find that $B=1 \implies y_k^p=k^2(-2)^k $, which, even after I try to rewrite what WolframAlpha answers, is not even near (I know that the first part of WolframAlpha's answer is the homogeneous part).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are almost there, try $-k^2(-2)^k$ :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, mastrok! Is that because B should equal $-1$?

Comment: You are right, $B=-1$

Comment: Thank you for your help :)